# JavaScript mouse event dragging like map

Tags: javascript

I want to implement drag events using mouse move/down/up like Google Maps.

Here's an example code [link](https://codepen.io/pmx/pen/jOXyKeQ)
(There are example gif too).

```js
scale.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (drag) {
    const mouseX = event.clientX - scale.offsetLeft;
    const mouseY = event.clientY - scale.offsetTop;
    const percentageX = (mouseX / scale.offsetWidth) * 100;
    const percentageY = (mouseY / scale.offsetHeight) * 100;
    scale.style.transformOrigin = `${100 - percentageX}% ${100 - percentageY}%`;
  }
});
```

This is the logic when drag event.

Press the button on this code to expand the map (using transform scale) and drag the map to move(using transform-origin).

But the coordinates are a little weird when first drag it.

for example, after zoom-in, when I mousedown in Egypt and mouse move to center, at that moment transform-origin set weird coordinate.

How can I solve this?

I try to change clientX, clientY logic but didn't work.